# Does anyone pre-juice their fruit juice for sale?

Tags: fruit, food-preservation, juice

I would like to know if there are stores out there that that pre-juice their fruit juices on the eve of sale, perhaps for 24-hours only since juicing. Have they been successful? What are the methods and protocols they might be using in in-house juicing/packaging/storing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about business practices are outside our scope.

Comment: @Jay : of course, it'd still be a perfectly fair question to ask about the effect of juicing the night before so you don't have to do it in the morning, and how best to hold it to minimize loss of quality.  There are plenty of questions about business on here (safety when bottling sauces, scaling up recipes, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There are.  There was a story on a local station about JRINK when they hit some anniversary a year or so ago.  (It might've also been about the owners ... being successful female, minority millenials)

They're doing some sort of 'single page app' thing on [their website](http://jrinkjuicery.com/collections/reboot), so I can't link straight to their about page  or FAQ, but it confirms that they're juicing & bottling.  (so people can do the 'grab and go' thing) :

> Why We're Different
>
> ...
>
> 3. Locally made every night, we delivery [sic] straight to your door and our stores daily.

...

> How long will JRINKs last?
>
> Because they are raw and cold-pressed, JRINKs will last up to 5 days if refrigerated and unopened.  Nut milks are ~3 days due to the fatty acid component, leading to higher rates of oxidization.  If you drink more than 2 a day, we suggest waiting at least 2-3 hours between each JRINK.  Once opened, please consume within the next 3 hours.  All our juices are date labeled upon producing and we ask that you JRINK responsibly (i.e. keep them cold!).

I have no idea what their process is, nor what the quality is ... I just know that it exists, and their model seems to be successful for the market they're in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just went ahead and launched it in my shop. People love it, and it keeps "vibrant" up until before closing time. So maybe 18 hours max since juicing is the best time to serve it.

I just happen to double-vacuum it on the Foodsaver before storing in the fridge. The fruits also chill in the fridge prior to juicing.